# ElasticSearch Service "Cannot create Java"

Tags: jvm, elasticsearch

we use ElasticSearch in a distributed environment. I tried to update the JDK from 1.6.x to 1.7.0_51. But when I do that the ElasticSearch Service cannot be started anymore.
Environment:
Win Server 2008
ElasticSearch 0.90
JDK 1.7.0_51
JAVA_HOME is set and functional (otherwise my JBoss would mention the missing JDK)

When I use the batch, ElasticSearch starts normally. Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_Home was ignored, so I tried to install a JRE
And this was the fix. I don't know why the JDK ignored.